# How to cleanup an SVN checkout with lots of locks in externals

Tags: shell, svn

At the moment `svn cleanup` doesn't go into externals according to this [bug](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=2325). What's the best way to remove all the checkout locks from a project and all it's externals?

Answer (score 0):

My best attempt is:

```
svn propget svn:externals |\
  grep '^[^# ]' |\
  cut -d ' ' -f 1 |\
  while read dir; do (cd $dir && svn cleanup); done
```

run at the level that the externals are defined (which works for me).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a better regex or format specifier you can pass to `svn status`, but I end up pruning the first 8 characters and passing to `xargs` for lots of things (externals list, modified files, etc.). For this particular example, I'd do:

```
svn st | grep ^X | sed 's/........//' | xargs svn cleanup
```

If I have a known list of directories, I'll sometimes also use a foreach:

```
for m in `cat modules`; do svn something $m; done
```

or

```
for m in one two three; do svn something $m; done
```